# ignoring declared target(s) 'swift-nio-zlib-support' in the system package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftpm

I'm getting this warning from SPM (I think) since upgrading to Xcode 12.5 and I have two questions:

1. What does it mean?
2. What can I do to solve/hide it?

Would be thankful for any responses. I found no good answers to these questions on Google.

Comment: I also got the same issue right after updating to Xcode 12.5. Do you suspect a specific dependency that could be doing this?

Comment: Yes I have a SwiftPM dependency on Apollo which has a dependency on Starscream which has a dependency on swift-nio-zlib-support.

Comment: I have same problem with Apollo and Starscream. Maybe try to upvode opened issue (#4) in swift-nio-zlib-support github.

Comment: I filed an issue with Starscream now also.

Comment: Yea I can confirm I am also using Apollo and Starscream. I will upvote the issue.

Comment: Also Apollo / Starscream

Answer (score 4):

There is opened pull request in [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/pull/844) github which is solving this warning. It will be fixed soon otherwise you can see files changed with solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is happen when you have multiple targets and you did't add Framework and libraries in all target

You can fix it by adding Framework and libraries in all target
Go to
Project > General > Targets > Framework and libraries
Then add Framework and libraries to all targets which require it

Comment: Not sure that's always the case.  I'm getting the warning with a Package that has a single target with no dependencies.